# Get parameter from static context in axis2

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, java-ee-6

While trying to move an axis2 web-app from glassfish3 to tomcat6, I can't seem to find a way to get a config parameter from a static context.

In glassfish3, a system property was defined in a far away place and read from the application using `System.getProperty(String name)`. Not only does the web agree that this is not the way to go for a web application, this trick is just not feasible for tomcat [(tomcat docs)](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#Can_I_set_Java_system_properties_differently_for_each_webapp.3F%29).

Reading parameters from the `ServletContext` is also not feasible as the app uses axis2 and I can't seem to find a way to access any kind of servlet voodoo from the static context that initializes the app's configuration.

`services.xml` (the file containing the service description for axis2) can contain `<parameter>` nodes, so that seems a nice place to configure the configuration location, but I can't seem to find a way to read these parameters from the application.

So in short: any ideas on how to get a value configured outside the application's code available from a static context?

---

(answer listed here as StackOverflow does not allow me to answer my own question...)

After scouring the Internet some more, a solution was found using an implementation of `org.apache.axis2.engine.ServiceLifeCycle`, which could read a parameter in the `startUp`-method as such:

```java
Parameter param = service.getParameter("name");
if (param != null) {
    saveParamValue(param.getValue().toString());
} else {
    // log warning on falling back to System.getProperty()
}
```

The life cycle class is attached using `class="fully.qualified.ClassName"` on the `<service>` node of the `services.xml` file used by axis2.

This works, now the application just crashes on something else (but that has little to with this issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in `services.xml` can be accessed by getting the `ServiceContext` object for the service, then calling `ServiceContext.getParameter()`. If your service implementation class implements the [Lifecycle](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/service/Lifecycle.html) interface, then Axis2 will call `Lifecycle.init()` every time it creates a new instance of the service class. The argument to `Lifecycle.init()` is the service's `ServiceContext`. Your `init()` implementation could save the context object or look up the parameters that you're interested in.